# apache rewriting - rewirte url to subfolder but nof if a certain segment is in url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a cms (TYPO3) installed in the folder cms. In order to get a nice url, i'm using

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ ./cms/$1

to get the address witout the cms-segment (http://example.com instead of http://example.com/cms

It seems to work as expected, but now I have another programm installed in a subdirectory called temp.

How can I manage it, that http://example.com/temp leads to this directory (address)? In other words: what rule manages the exeption?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /cms/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(temp|old)/ [NC] does the trick.